# How to replace a string with hash in ruby, using .gsubs?

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby and I need to create a template which replaces my strings with hashes that I write. What I need to add in my code?

This is my code, I write two methods for my task, help please with your suggestions

```
class Template 

  def initialize(template_string, local_variables)
    @template_string = template_string
    @local_variables = local_variables
  end 

  def compile()
    @template_string.gsub()
  end
end



puts Template.new("I like %{x}", x:"coffee").compile # x = coffee
puts Template.new("x = %{x}", y:5).compile # unknown x
puts Template.new("x = %{x}", x:5, y:3).compile # x = 5, ignores y
```

Comment: What's your expected result? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: As i understand i want that in answer it was "I like coffee" and "x = 5"

Answer (score 1):

For first please read how to use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) method. Then rewrite `Template#compile` like this:

```rb
 def compile
  compiled = @template_string.dup

  @local_variables.each do |k, v|
    compiled.gsub!("%{#{k}}", String(v))
  end

  compiled
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried it and in the response i see this
```Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from task.rb:12:in `<main>'
        1: from task.rb:12:in `new'
task.rb:3:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `gsub`. Just use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-25) format specifications.

```
def compile
  @template_string % @local_variables
end
```

The whole example:

```
class Template
  def initialize(template_string, local_variables)
    @template_string = template_string
    @local_variables = local_variables
  end 

  def compile
    @template_string % @local_variables
  end
end

Template.new("I like %{x}", x: "coffee").compile
#=> "I like coffee"

Template.new("x = %{x}", y: 5).compile
#=> KeyError (key{x} not found)

Template.new("x = %{x}", x: 5, y: 3).compile
#=> "x = 5"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried it and in the response i see this
```Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from task.rb:12:in `<main>'
        1: from task.rb:12:in `new'
task.rb:3:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)```

Comment: Please, double check that your `initialize` method expects 2 arguments, like this: `def initialize(template_string, local_variables)`!

Comment: Please consider upvoting an answer when it was helpful and accepting it when it solved your problem. This is a way to say thank you to the answerer and to indicate to others that the issue was fixed.